# Why am I getting the Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' error among other errors?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors

So I'm very new to pointers and pointer syntax, and I've just written this function but have about 5-6 build errors and after looking at the code for a while, I'm still unsure on how to fix them or why they are errors. I'm new to pointers and memory so that is why I am unsure regarding how to fix these bugs and why they are wrong. Thanks for your help it is appreciated it!

```
int makeFrequency (int data[], int dSize, int *minDataValue, int     *maxDataValue)
{

  findMinAndMax(data, dSize, minDataValue, maxDataValue);

  int fSize = *minDataValue + *maxDataValue; // invalid operands of types 'int' and 'int*' to binary 'operator+' error?

  int frequency = new int [fSize]; //invalid conversion error?

  if (frequency == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= fSize; i++)
  {
    frequency[i] = 0; // invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript error?
  }


      for (int i = 0; i <= dSize; i++)
      {
        int j = data[i] - (*minDataValue)+1; // invalid operands of types 'int' and 'int*' to binary 'operator-' error?
        frequency[j] = frequency[j] + 1; // invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript error?
      }

      return frequency;
    }

int main() {

  int dSize;
  int *ArrayOfInts;

  cout << "How many data values? ";
  cin >> dSize;

  ArrayOfInts = new int [dSize];

  getData(dSize, ArrayOfInts);

  int *frequency, min, max;

  frequency = makeFrequency (ArrayOfInts, dSize, &min, &max); // invalid conversion error?

  if (frequency == NULL) return -1;

  makeHistogram(frequency, min, max);

  delete [] frequency;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change to `int* makeFrequency(...)` and `int* frequency = new...`.

Comment: "`int fSize = *minDataValue + *maxDataValue; // invalid operands of types 'int' and 'int*' to binary 'operator+' error?`" - unless there's something you're not showing us, or that's not your real code, you **don't** get that error.

Comment: `new` always returns a pointer, but `frequency` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int frequency = new int [fSize]; //invalid conversion error?
```

`new` returns a pointer to the heap-allocated object. When you allocate `X`, `new` return an `X *`.

`new X[n]` allocates `n` instances of `X` and returns a pointer to the first instance of X.

(In all cases, `new` also invokes the allocated objects' constructors, but this is an irrelevant point here).

```
new int [fSize];
```

Therefore, this expression returns an `int *`.

```
int frequency
```

`frequency` is, obviously an `int`.

```
int frequency = new int [fSize];
```

Putting all of the above together, here you are attempting to assign an `int *` to an `int`. That's your conversion error. `frequency` should be declared as an `int *`.

Comment: The `makeFrequency` function also needs to return an `int *`.

Comment: Oh okay, I see now, I was unsure what it meant. Thank you!